# How do you connect to an EPP server (domain registry) in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, registrar, epp

I'm building a project to manage my own domain names (just for learning purposes). The standard for interfacing with the registry API is to use their EPP server on port 700 with your username, password, and an SSL cert on the client side.

How do I connect to this in node js? Should I open a TLS connection? Their documentation is vague, at best, so if anyone has had any experience doing this, that would help out.

It's also hard testing because I'm not sure if my ip was properly whitelisted. Would like to see a sample code snippet connecting to an EPP server with username, password, and SSL cert, or perhaps just point me in the right direction as I'm most likely overthinking it :p.

Here's where I've started found from the only example online I can find in node.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var tls = require('tls')

var options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  passphrase: 'passphrase',
  username: 'username', // ?
}

var stream = tls.connect(700, 'example.com', options);
  stream.setEncoding('utf8')
  stream.on('secureConnect', function() {
  console.log('client connected')
})
stream.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

But that doesn't do anything and won't make the connection.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Added. Its nothing really because I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Helped my answer to you somehow?

Comment: The code to connect to the EPP server looks correct (to me), but I haven't been able to make a successful connection yet due to (what I think) invalid certificate issues. I'm still unable to resolve them and currently working with the registry.

Comment: Try connecting with `openssl s_client` and your certificate. As soon as you get the EPP greeting back that way it means that your IP is correctly whitelisted and then your certificate is correctly recognised by the server. After that you can try to do the same from your program.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right [RFC EPP can be connected by TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5734).

I would use [Node.JS API net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) to create client.

And by [EPP documentation](https://www.nic.lv/eppdoc/html/epp.html#client-request) after connect you need send [command in this format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5730#section-2.5) for [example login](https://www.nic.lv/eppdoc/html/session/login.html).

```js
var host = 'example.com';
var port = 700;
var command = '{{xml_command}}';

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write(command);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

As an alternative I'd try [node-epp](https://github.com/heytrav/nodepp) and [epp-reg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/epp-reg).

Maybe I helped where to go next.

Comment: No, this does not implement EPP correctly. See RFC5734 section 4, each EPP frame must be following its size encoded in 4 bytes. Also per its section 3, the server speaks first with a greeting message.

Comment: OK thx @PatrickMevzek - "hello message" make sense - Q can you offer solution how should it looks like?

Comment: While I know a lot about EPP, I know nothing about NodeJS. So I can only say you need to follow this path: 1) establish the TLS connection properly (deal with certificate issues, etc.) 2) open the socket 3) read the server message (read the first 4 bytes - but remember that they can come in fragmented packets, then read an amount of data equal to the size encoded in these 4 bytes), that will be a greeting 4), reply with a login (again encoding size as first 4 bytes) 5) read server reply if any, check result code and go back to 3)